# Homotopy classes of continuous functions $\Sigma_g \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}P^2$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Does anyone know a good description of homotopy classes of continuous functions $\Sigma_g \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}P^2$, where $\Sigma_g$ is the closed oriented surface of genus $g > 1$.

Thanks for the attention!

Comment: See the paper "Homotopy classification the JHC Whitehead way"  by G. Ellis, Exposition. Math. 6 (2) (1988) 97–110. available at http://.groupoids.org.uk/pdffiles/Ellis-homclass.pdf .

Comment: @RonnieBrown Sorry, but your link is broken. It seems [this](http://www.groupoids.org.uk/pdffiles/Ellis-homclass.pdf) works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This   [mathstackexchange answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36488/how-to-compute-homotopy-classes-of-maps-on-the-2-torus)  gives a nice description of the set of homotopy class of maps from $T^2=\Sigma_1$ to any space $X$, and includes a particular mention of the example $X={\mathbb R}P^2$. Answers to this  [mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/110444/determining-homotopy-classes-t2-rp2)  give a couple of other ways to calculate the set $[T^2, {\mathbb R}P^2]$. It seems to me that all these methods can be extended to general orientable surfaces. The answer is as follows: there are ${\mathbb N}$ homotopy classes of maps that induce zero on $H_1$, plus $(2^{2g}-1)\cdot 2$ maps that are not zero on $H_1$ (there are two homotopy classes for each possible non-zero homomorphism on $H_1$).

Comment: You are right of course. I was wondering if a map to non-orientable surface can have an integer-valued degree, but at least for $S^2$ this is possible. Maybe I should have read Ellis' paper more carefully.

Comment: Thank you very much for all these reference I found everything I need in it :)

Comment: I mention that in order to show an idea of available methods,  Example 12.3.13 of  the book "Nonabelian Algebraic Topology", advertised at http://groupoids.org.uk/nonab-a-t.html , gives an example  of calculating some homotopy classes of maps $K \to Y$ where $K$ is the product of two copies of $\mathbb RP^2$ and $Y$ is $\mathbb RP^3$ with homotopy groups killed above dimension 3.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the following [article](http://dx.doi.org/10.7146/math.scand.a-15092) might be useful. It is written by Daciberg L. Gonçalves and Mauro Spreafico, with the title "THE FUNDAMENTAL GROUP OF THE SPACE OF MAPS FROM A SURFACE INTO THE PROJECTIVE PLANE".